# Is this URL encoding safe?

Tags: javascript, php, security

On my site, I need to redirect my js script back to my backend running PHP. Is the below considered safe to do? Safe as in safe from XSS or any other issues.

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo get_payment_receipt_page_link( $order_id ) . '?currency_code='. urlencode($currency); ?>' + '&user_wallet=' + encodeURIComponent(walletAddress) + '&txn_hash=' + encodeURIComponent(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of `$order`, `$currency`, `walletAddress` or `result` is comes from user input, it's not. Otherwise, it is.

Comment: They are not from user. Thank you! But if they come from user, what should I do? Is my code still safe?

Comment: You might move your redirection logic to your backend and put it into a few validations like escaping characters like `<>\`, url validation with regex, etc... & then do the redirection.